# TestFlight feedback button missing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Has anyone manages to enable the send feedback button in TestFlight builds (Apple's TestFlight beta testing via iTunes Connect).

My build is uploaded fine, I've invited the external testers, build passed review and became available and I've filled the feedback email field but none of my testers sees the "Send Feedback" button in the TestFlight app. Anyone else experiencing the same?

Comment: Yep same here, no feedback button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this was a glitch on Apple's end, which was silently fixed and now the "Send Feedback" button is visible (without the need to update a new beta build or an update to the TestFlight app).

Answer (score 0):

If You still have this problem in 2018, You may find this Apple support answer useful:

"... the tester should have Apple Mail configured on the device from which he can send an email. (It does not mean that the email address should be an Apple ID, but it should be configured with Apple Mail)."

So first, check if You have feedback e-mail added in Testflight, second, You don't control this - tester has to have Apple Mail app configured which few people do.